# Is there a Java number formatting library that handles significant digits?

Tags: java, number-formatting

The built in DecimalFormat only allows you to specify number of digits to the right of the decimal place.

Because of the limitations of representing numbers as double, number formatting needs to include some level of rounding inside of it. In the general case, that rounding has to be to a number of significant digits (default case is the precision of a double) or else your formatted double will end up showing stuff like 3.5999999 instead of 3.6.

The closest solution I could find is using

```
new BigDecimal(double, new MathContext(14, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString()
```

however, that only provides a single format. If I need to format it generally (group separator, decimal separator, limit to number of digits, padding, etc.), there is nothing in the JDK library.

Is there a general number formatting library out there that will handle rounding to significant digits properly?

Someone asked for examples. So, let's say I wanted to format to 4 significant digits, then:

```
0.000003599999 -> 0.0000036
4.12345 -> 4.123
1234.345 -> 1234
```

The general approach we would take would be to round to 14 digits since depending on the circumstances, a double can only represent around 15-17 significant digits anyway (or so I've read).

Comment: To give more clarity, I suggest you post a couple of examples as to what you expect the output to be for a given input.

Comment: Note that there are precision problems with the `new BigDecimal(double)` constructor, as well as with the version taking the MathContext. Use `BigDecimal.valueOf(...)` instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This adds a lot of overhead (5 MB or so), but the International Components for Unicode project has an enhanced DecimalFormat that handles significant digits nicely.

http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/DecimalFormat.html#sigdig

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat();
formatter.setMaximumSignificantDigits( 4 );
System.out.println( formatter.format( hoursSinceLastAccident ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I had to add `setSignificantDigitsUsed(true)` to ensure the significant digits were used.

Answer (score 5):

It's worth mentioning that if it's specifically **Android** and not Java that's being targeted, the built in `DecimalFormat` supports formatting for significant figures via the `@` symbol.

```
String smallPi = new DecimalFormat("@@@").format("3.14159"); // formats number as '3.14'
```

Comment: The class `android.icu.text.DecimalFormat` supports the "@" symbol to represent significant figures, but the regular `java.text.DecimalFormat` does not.

Answer (score 4):

What about such solution:

```
double l = 34563.35129854289;
short offset = (short) Math.ceil(Math.log10(l) + 1);
short significantDigits = 10;

System.out.printf("%,." + (significantDigits - offset) + "f", l);
//String output = String.format("%,." + (significantDigits - offset) + "f", l);
```

Output:

34 563,3513 (i.e. ',' in printf indicates to use group separator)

Comment: The question was "Is there a general number formatting library that...". Your solution is useful and interesting, though limited to what printf offers. One could take a similar approach and create a DecimalFormat on the fly, but either way is somewhat of a hack and I would be concerned about corner cases and correct rounding.

Comment: @taotree, you can use the same hack for `String.format()`. You could even build your own `NumberFormat` on top of it. It might not be the most efficient way to do it, though...

Comment: This will fail for some numbers due to rounding issues. Never use `log10` to get a number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

I found this nice way of doing it.

This is if you just want to print it out.

```
public String toSignificantFiguresString(BigDecimal bd, int significantFigures){
    return String.format("%."+significantFigures+"G", bd);
}
```

This is if you want to convert it:

```
public BigDecimal toSignificantFigures(BigDecimal bd, int significantFigures){
    String s = String.format("%."+significantFigures+"G", bd);
    BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(s);
    return result;
}
```

Here's an example of it in action:

```
    BigDecimal bd2 = toSignificantFigures(BigDecimal.valueOf(4.12345), 4);
    BigDecimal bd3 = toSignificantFigures(BigDecimal.valueOf(1234.345), 4);
    BigDecimal bd4 = toSignificantFigures(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.000003599999), 4);

    System.out.println("bd2: " + String.format("%f",bd2));
    System.out.println("bd3: " + String.format("%f",bd3));
    System.out.println("bd4: " + String.format("%f",bd4));
```

Comment: Just make sure you have `Locale.US` when formatting the numbers or you'll get a NumberFormatException. (Also case bd4 doesn't seem right).