# Any neat way to limit significant figures with BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I want to round a Java `BigDecimal` to a certain number of significant digits (NOT decimal places), e.g. to 4 digits:

```
12.3456 => 12.35
123.456 => 123.5
123456 => 123500
```

etc. The basic problem is how to find the order of magnitude of the `BigDecimal`, so I can then decide how many place to use after the decimal point.

All I can think of is some horrible loop, dividing by 10 until the result is <1, I am hoping there is a better way.

BTW, the number might be very big (or very small) so I can't convert it to double to use Log on it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easierst solution is:

```
  int newScale = 4-bd.precision()+bd.scale();
  BigDecimal bd2 = bd1.setScale(newScale, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

No String conversion is necessary, it is based purely on `BigDecimal` arithmetic and therefore as efficient as possible, you can choose the `RoundingMode` and it is small. If the output should be a `String`, simply append `.toPlainString()`.

Comment: This seems to work well in all cases, even when scientific notation kicks in for large and small values. The only minor problem is that if the result has no fractional part it converts to a string like 123 rather than 123.0 (which I prefer for my application) but that is extremely easy to fix of course. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. On my machine the output for "123" and "4 digits" _is_ "123.0". What could be the difference?

Comment: Oh I just noticed my code also uses stripTrailingZeros() - sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Because '123' to two sig figs is 1.2 x 10, and so is '120'. '120.0' is 4 significant figures.

Comment: another way of doing it using built in method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474742/is-there-a-java-number-formatting-library-that-handles-significant-digits

Comment: I'm reviving this old post as this still seems like the most elegant (and correct) way to format the significant digits from a `BigDecimal`. It's really strange that JDK doesn't have anything built-in for this purpose.

Comment: However, I've noticed a couple of edge cases that produce a "one too big" `newScale` using this solution: this happens when the rounding up of the result causes the leftmost digit to roll over to the left, e.g. `0.99999 -> 1.0000` or `0.099999 ->  0.10000`. These cases could be fixed by adding some conditional logic after the rounding, but I was wondering if that logic could be incorporated into the one-liner that calculates `newScale`?

Answer (score 16):

Why not just use `round(MathContext)`?

```
BigDecimal value = BigDecimal.valueOf(123456);
BigDecimal wantedValue = value.round(new MathContext(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
```

Comment: `MathContext` is kind of a blind spot for me, but here it is a good match.

Comment: Well, it just encapsulates the wanted precision and the rounding mode, nothing more.

Comment: I never had the need for that but I'm craving for a built-in encapsulation of _scale_ and rounding mode.

Comment: @A.H. you haven't had a need until you try to divide 1/3 and have an exception thrown as it repeats forever. As just happened with me :) Though that default behavior makes sense as it's supposed to be infinite precision.

Comment: @KennyCason: I don't understand what you mean. If I use `divide(divisor, scale, ROUNDING_MODE)` then there is a defined end. In this case the end of computation is defined by __scale__, not by __precision__. My statement is, that `MathContext` does not allow easy encapsualation of __scale__ and rounding mode, only for __precision__ and rounding mode.

Comment: @A.H. Ah, I see what you meant.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following lines:

```
int digitsRemain = 4;

BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("12.3456");
int power = bd.precision() - digitsRemain;
BigDecimal unit = bd.ulp().scaleByPowerOfTen(power);
BigDecimal result = bd.divideToIntegralValue(unit).multiply(unit);
```

Note: this solution always rounds down to the last digit.

Comment: Did not know that BigDecimal did this.  Nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

Someone will probably come up with a better solution, but the first thing that comes to mind is chuck it in to a StringBuilder, check whether it contains a '.' and return an appropriate length substring. E.g.:

```
int n = 5;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("" + number);
if (sb.indexOf(".") > 0)
{
    n++;
}
BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(sb.substring(0, n));
```

Comment: This seems good, though some rounding off will be required too.

Comment: Thanks, that's better than my idea.

Answer (score 0):

To me this seems as simple as:
Given N = 5, D = 123.456789

1. get the string representation of the number, "123.456789"
2. retrieve the first N-1 digits of the number, "123.4"
3. evaluate D[N] and D[N+1], in this case "5" and "6"
4. 6 meets the criteria for rounding up (6 > 4), therefore carry 1 and make D[N] = 5+1 = 6
5. D post rounding is now 123.46

Order can be calculated using Math.floor(Math.log(D)).

hope this helps.

Comment: He specifically said he couldn't use Math.log().

Comment: @Thor84no - argh, missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Since BigDecimal is basically a string, perhaps this:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Silly {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("1.23238756843723E+5");
        String valueString = value.toPlainString();
        int decimalIndex = valueString.indexOf( '.' );
        System.out.println( value + " has " +
            (decimalIndex < 0 ? valueString.length() : decimalIndex) +
            " digits to the left of the decimal" );
    }
}
```

Which produces this:

```
123238.756843723 has 6 digits to the left of the decimal
```

Answer (score 0):

[A.H.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7572524/14731) is technically correct, but here is a more general (and easier to understand) solution:

```
import static org.bitbucket.cowwoc.requirements.core.Requirements.assertThat;

/**
 * @param value            a BigDecimal
 * @param desiredPrecision the desired precision of {@code value}
 * @param roundingMode     the rounding mode to use
 * @return a BigDecimal with the desired precision
 * @throws NullPointerException if any of the arguments are null
 */
public BigDecimal setPrecision(BigDecimal value, int desiredPrecision, RoundingMode roundingMode)
{
    assertThat("value", value).isNotNull();
    assertThat("roundingMode", roundingMode).isNotNull();
    int decreaseScaleBy = value.precision() - desiredPrecision;
    return value.setScale(value.scale() - decreaseScaleBy, roundingMode);
}
```