# logical decimal formatting in java

Tags: java, formatting, decimal-point

When it comes to formatting decimals in java there is one approach i know of

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
```

but this is not working if you may have values such as

```
0.0000054654654 or similar
```

in that case you'll just get

```
0.00
```

while more logically it would make sence to print

```
0.0000054 (or maybe 0.0000055)
```

I wonder if there is already a solution for this? or i have to implement custom formatter?

examples that might be there

1.1           -> 1.100
0.00000011111 -> 0.000000111

you can see that instead of hardcoding how many digits after decimal point we want, we need to tell how many digits we want after first digit... (roughly)

Comment: Why don't you use `"#0.000000"`?

Comment: Might work, but lets assume we need exactly to show all those 0's
cos frankly some people get confused with scientific notation numbers

Comment: @Christian because with that formatter i'll get too many zeroes for numbers like 1.1 -> 1.100000 which is not what we want

Answer (score 0):

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
```

The number of 0s specifies the precision.
If you want 0.0000054654654 to be formatted to 0.0000055, use:
    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.000000");

If required precision in not known upfront, the following approach may be used:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double a = 0.0000054654654;
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(a);
    String answer = String.format("%."+3+"G", bd);
    System.out.println(answer);
}
```

Comment: the problem is that you dont know if you'll get 1.1 or 0.000000023423, in your case if i use #0.000000 and have 0.00000000000000123 then i'll get another 0.0000000 output

Comment: I think the op wants 2 significant digitis - so for example: 1 -> 1.0, 1.123 -> 1.12, 0.000023 -> 0.00023

Comment: exactly, i've updated question also to make that clear... i think this might be a common issue thats why i expect some solution already done for it (before i invent another bike)

Comment: ahh, understood. Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487506/built-in-methods-for-displaying-significant-figures/19506712#19506712

Comment: I've tried it, thanks for reference, its interesting yet not exactly what is needed...