# How to leave only 4 decimals after number bigger than 0?

Tags: java

I don't know how to explain this well, but for example I have a number:
`0.00000548347554` and want to make `0.000005483` from it, or
`0.0683453248` to `0.06843`, etc.

Comment: I'd say convert to string, start traversing until you find a non-zero after the dot and then count another four characters. Then cut to there with `substring`. I can't think of a way to do it with calculations or something from the standard library.

Comment: I am not aware of any functions that provide this capability. Maybe use a hack approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474742/is-there-a-java-number-formatting-library-that-handles-significant-digits/6092978

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes your number is a string:

```
String tmp = "0.0683453248";

String[] tmpA = tmp.split("");
ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < tmpA.length; i++){
    res.add(tmpA[i]);

    if(!tmpA[i].equals(".") && Integer.parseInt(tmpA[i]) > 0){
        res.add(tmpA[i + 1]);
        res.add(tmpA[i + 2]);
        res.add(tmpA[i + 3]);
        break;
    }

}

String result = String.join("",res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [solution from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25307973/10819573), you can convert the given number into a string and then use the regex replacement to get the required string out of it.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(doubleToString(0.00000548347554));
        System.out.println(doubleToString(0.0683453248));
    }

    static String doubleToString(double n) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH));
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(340);
        return df.format(n).replaceAll("(\\d*\\.0*[1-9]{4})\\d*", "$1");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0.000005483
0.06834
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/H5vBrn)

**Explanation of the regex**:

- `(`: Start of capturing group#1

  - `\\d*\\.`: Digit(s) followed by `.`
  - `0*`: Any number of zeros
  - `[1-9]{4}`: Non-zero four digits
- `)`: End of capturing group#1
- `\d*` : Any digit any number of times

Answer (score 0):

For small numbers `BigDecimal` can be used:

```
BigDecimal significant(double number, int count) {
    if (count < 1) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid count: " + count);
    BigDecimal big = BigDecimal.valueOf(number);
    if (big.precision() <= count) {
        return big;
    } else {
        return big.setScale(big.scale()-big.precision()+count, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
    }
}
```

`precision()` returns the number of *significant* digits;
the method changes the scale so only the desired number of digits is present.
The `if` is used to avoid more zeros than the input if this has less than `count` digits.

Use `doubleValue()` to convert the result to `double` if needed (may *suffer* from rounding error).
To get a string, use `toPlainString()`, which will transform the result to string without using the exponential notation.

Rounding mode can also be changed if desired.

Note: it can also be used with larger numbers, it basically will replace digits by zero like in `significant(12345,2)` -> `12000` (or `1.2E+4`)